# VS Code fails to launch Bash

Tags: visual-studio-code

Added Bash as a default shell in VS Code but it fails to launch, anyone know why? (Screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Code 127 means the program couldn't be found on PATH. Have you double checked if it exists under the given path?

Comment: Is bashed install on your machine?

Comment: @DirkR yes just checked again, bash.exe is right where VS Code says it is...

Comment: It's hard to say from a picture but `Program Files` has a space and doesn't look quoted.